# Checking for template parent class in C++ using SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, sfinae

I've been learning the concept of SFINAE in C++ recentlly and I am currentlly trying to use it in a project.

The thing is, what I'm trying to do is different than anything I could find, and I can't figure out how to do it.

Let's say I have a template class called MyParent:

```
template <typename Elem>
class MyParent;
```

And a non-template class called MyClass, that inherites it, using char as Elem:

```
class MyClass : public MyParent<char>;
```

Now, I want to use SFINAE in order to check if a typename inherites `MyParent`, regardless of what `Elem` type is used.

I can't use `std::is_base_of`, because of the parent's template.

I've tried to do the following:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_my_parent : std::false_type {};
template <typename Elem>
struct is_my_parent<MyParent<Elem>> : std::true_type {};
```

Now, if I check for `is_my_parent<MyParent<Elem>>::value`, it gives me `true`. Which is good.
However, when I check for `is_my_parent<MyClass>::value`, I recive `false`. Which kind of makes sence because `MyClass` isn't actually `MyParent<Elem>`, but I didn't manage to get what I wanted.

Is there any convenient way to achive such a thing in C++, other than defining `is_my_parent` for each and every class that inherites from `MyParent`?

Comment: You could add to each class, `using parent_t = MyParent<template_type>;`, and then you can check that.  Trying to code something that checks if this class inherit from any `MyParent<T>` is basically impossible to do, as there is an infinite set of types `T` could be.

Comment: You could have `MyParent` templates inherit from an empty `class MyParentCommonBase{};`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might do

```
template <typename T>
std::true_type is_my_parent_impl(const MyParent<T>*);

std::false_type is_my_parent_impl(const void*);

template <typename T>
using is_my_parent = decltype(is_my_parent_impl(std::declval<T*>()));
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xh1r4KKv7)

Comment: I like this solution, very simple and straight-forward. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any convenient way to achive such a thing in C++, other than defining is_my_parent for each and every class that inherites from MyParent?

There is, but you'll need to use more elaborate meta-programming techniques. Go entirely back to basics, as it were.

```
template <class C>
class is_my_parent {
    using yes = char;
    using no  = char[2];
    
    template<typename t>
    static yes& check(MyParent<t> const*);

    static no& check(...);

public:
    enum { value = (1 == sizeof check(static_cast<C*>(0))) };
};
```

It relies on two basic properties of function overloading and templates:

1. A derived class can be used to match a function template that takes a base class template as an argument.
2. Ellipsis offer a conversion sequence that is always considered worse than any other.

Then it's just a matter of inspecting the return type of the chosen overload to determine what we got. Other than the type alias, you can even use this in C++03. Or you can modernize it, so long as overload resolution does the work for you, the check will be performed just the same.

Comment: I'm actually familiar with this type of implementation, except I usually prefer using uint8_t and uint16_t instead of char and char[2]. If I coul'd mark two answers as helpful, I would have marked this one as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I like Jarod42's answer much better, but an actual SNINAE approach somewhat close to your attempt can work.  Here's what I came up with.

To use the type_traits to answer this, we need to know the type of the element. We can make `MyParent` expose it:

```
template <typename Elem>
class MyParent {
public:
    using ElemType = Elem;
};
```

Then the default (false) `is_my_parent` takes an extra arg and the `void_t` technique* can be used:

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_my_parent : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_my_parent<T, std::void_t<typename T::ElemType>> : 
    std::is_base_of<MyParent<typename T::ElemType>, T>::type {};
```

The specialization is only valid if ElemType is an accessible type in T, and then it results in std::true|false type if the inheritance relationship holds.

live example: https://godbolt.org/z/na5637Knd

But not only is the function overload resolution a better approach for simplicity and size, it will also compile much faster.

(*) void_t was exposed to the world in this fantastic 2-part 2014 talk by Walter Brown.  Recommended even if only for review.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Am2is2QCvxY